# Show only headers in outline mode when I open my dot emacs

Tags: init-file, outline-mode

I use `outline-minor-mode` to organize my .emacs file. I have this code at the end to activate it in the file:

```
;;; Local Variables:
;;; eval: (outline-minor-mode 1)
;;; eval: (hide-body)
;;; outline-regexp: "^;;; "
;;; End:
```

When the file opens however, it shows all the contents, but I would like to see only the headings. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you call `org-overview`, does that give you the visual appearance you are looking for?  You do *not* need an `org-mode` major-mode buffer for that to work.  If so, then you can try putting an `eval:` of that into your file local variables.  Also, have a look at the functions `org-content` and related functions -- type `M-x find-function` to trace and see what other functions might help you achieve your goal.

Comment: @RaoulComninos: please make your comment an answer (and assuming that you find it answers your question :-), you can also go ahead and accept it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the incorrect function. Using `find-function` I discovered that the correct function is `outline-hide-subtree`. My dot emacs now has these local variables:

```
;; Local Variables:
;; eval: (outline-minor-mode 1)
;; eval: (while (re-search-forward outline-regexp nil t) (outline-hide-subtree))
;; outline-regexp: "^;;; "
;; End:
```

When I open my dot emacs now, only headings (with this form: `;;; HEADING:`) appear. Many thanks to @lawlist.